# Parent listener $(this) listening to all selected child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user clicks on **add an item** a new item append on the parent element, then clicking on that item a textarea prompts to edit its text. 
HTML DOM / [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hasantg/67ndb0u8/)

```
<div class="editor"></div>
<a href="#" class="additem">add an item</a>
<div class="options">
    <br><b>Item Text</b> <br>
    <textarea class="itemtext"></textarea>
</div>
```

JS(jQuery) / [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hasantg/67ndb0u8/)

```
var $item    = "<div class='item'>Text here...</div>",
    $itembtn = $('a.additem'),
    $editor  = $('div.editor'),
    $opt = $('div.options');
$itembtn.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $editor.show();
    $editor.append($item);
});

$($editor).on('click', 'div.item', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $opt.show();
    $opt.find('textarea').val($this.text());
    $opt.find('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
        $this.text($opt.find('textarea').val());
    });
});

$($editor).on('blur', 'div.item', function(){
    $opt.hide();
});
```

But it seems that $(this) is not pointing to a single clicked element, instead it is pointing to all the clicked/selected child elements! 
[image]

And also the blur event is not working!
How i can point $this to only one selected item but not all the clicked items?

Comment: Your blur event isn't working because you're attaching it to the wrong element.

Comment: Purely for the sake of alternatives, instead of unbinding and binding the keyup handler, you could do the same with a variable that tracks the 'active' div: http://jsfiddle.net/67ndb0u8/1/ Not better or worse, mainly a case of still having the fiddle open in a background window ;)

Comment: @Me.Name that was smart 8)

Comment: @Me.Name i'm gonna use this, never thought of pushing an element and then referencing it! One more question, how do you insert new line from the textarea to the div.item? Thanks again

Comment: Glad you could use it. Easiest way is to use regex to replace the newlines with `<br>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/67ndb0u8/3/  ( `$curtxt.html($txt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>'));` inside the keyup event )

Comment: Made the fiddle into an answer for clarity, added a line that focuses the textbox and selects all text when the div is clicked, thought that might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to keep a variable of your current 'active' div (clicked div), and use that to set the text.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67ndb0u8/6/)

```
var $item    = "<div class='item'>Text here...</div>",
    $itembtn = $('a.additem'),
    $editor  = $('div.editor'),
    $opt = $('div.options'),
    $txt = $opt.find('textarea'),
    $curtxt;

$itembtn.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $editor.show();
    $($item).appendTo($editor).click(function(){
        $curtxt = $(this); 
        $txt.val($curtxt.text());
        $opt.show();
        $txt.select().focus();
    });    
});

$txt.keyup(function(){
    $curtxt.html($txt.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>'));
}).blur(function(){
    $opt.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this was easy...

Change this:

```
$($editor).on('click', 'div.item', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this);
    $opt.show();
    $opt.find('textarea').val($this.text());
    $opt.find('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
        $this.text($opt.find('textarea').val());
    });
});
```

Into this:

```
$($editor).on('click', 'div.item', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this);
    $opt.show();
    $opt.find('textarea').unbind('keyup').keyup(function(){
        $this.text($opt.find('textarea').val());
    }).val($this.text());
});
```

---

Since you are adding `.on([...])` per element, you are adding always a new event listener. You can `.unbind()` it so it won't be tied to that element. And then you re-bind it.

In this context, using `.on()` is **BAD**

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the keyup event destroy the keyup event you added on click of the div and yes its done

Use `$(element).off('keyup')` to unbind the previous keyup event and then add the current event using `$(element).on('keyup',function)`.

Check the snippet

```js
var $item    = "<div class='item'>Text here...</div>",
    $itembtn = $('a.additem'),
    $editor  = $('div.editor'),
    $opt = $('div.options');
$itembtn.on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    $editor.show();
    $editor.append($item);
});

$($editor).on('click', 'div.item', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $opt.show();
    
    var txtEd = $opt.find('textarea');
    txtEd.val($this.text());
    txtEd.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){
     $this.text($opt.find('textarea').val());
    });
});

$($editor).on('blur', 'div.item', function(){
    $opt.hide();
});
```

```css
.editor { margin: 20px 0px; border: 1px solid #888; padding: 5px; display: none; }
.item { background: #ccc; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; }
.options textarea { width: 80%; height: 100px; }
.options { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor"></div>
<a href="#" class="additem">add an item</a>
<div class="options">
    <br><b>Item Text</b> <br>
    <textarea class="itemtext"></textarea>
</div>
```